# How can i prevent my int function from string parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
def sum(c: int,d : int) -> int: 
    return c + d

a="a"
b="b"

if a<b:
    print (f"{a} is small")
    print (f"sum = {sum(a,b)}")
    print (type(sum(a,b)))
elif b<a:
    print (f"{b} is small")
    print (f"sum = {sum(a,b)}")
    print (type(sum(a,b)))
else:
    print ("equal")
```

and here is my output:

```
a is small
sum = ab
<class 'str'>
```

Why my integer function takes string parameter and why error does not appear?
How can I catch string input?

Thanks

Comment: They're type hints — nothing is enforced at runtime.

Comment: BTW don't override `sum` builtin

Comment: I wanna answer a decorator approach to enforce the return type of any method, post already closed. So if somebody want to restrict the return type anyways they can using decorators.

Comment: is overriding is risky?

Comment: I dont know but I have used decorators to validate the return type of any method, you can try too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python type annotations aren't checked at runtime. You can check your code for correctness using [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/), and some editors also make use of them to highlight potential problems.

Comment: how can i prevent my function from string parameters? Because i will take parameters from user.

Comment: That wouldn't be very pythonic, since Python is dynamically typed by design. But you could do `isinstance()` checks and raise exceptions if you feel you must.

Comment: @hyorman do `return int(c) + int(d)` this will throw an exception if a string is input. You would have to catch these exceptions with a `try:`; `except:` clause though

Comment: Thank you so much `return int(c) + int(d)` is really works. and `try: except:` mechanism is the really which i look for.